# unsaved settings

Tags: settings, system

Just had ubuntu 12.04 installed on my pc, the only problem I am discovering is that none of my settings are saving. Appearance-Behavior resets to default every time i reboot. My Thunderbird accounts are deleted and none of my bookmarks are being saved in Mozilla. Any way to fix this?

Comment: How did you installed it?. Looks like you are running it from a CD.

Comment: It was installed at another location, a friend who is a bit more techy than I did it for me. I use it from my home without a CD.

Comment: I suspect he simply copied the CD to the hard disk, making it an "live CD".

Comment: have you considered asking the friend who installed it?

Comment: I have not asked my friend, he has been tech support for the last 25yrs from a local agency that serves the whole southeast portion of our state. I assumed he would install it correctly. However, you never know until you ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the guest account, this will not save any settings.

Create and use a "real" account instead.

Comment: I thought that was the problem as my first log on was guest, but I've since logged in under my "real" account and still no settings are being saved.

Comment: Have you relevant errors into the `~/.xsession-errors` or `~/.xsession-errors.old` file?

Comment: no errors on start up just a request for password. regular boot, but it's like I'm booting for the first time with no personal settings. I have not tried to save a document or download an app or program to see if that saves after a reboot...will try it and comment in a bit.

Comment: It seems as though the guest account vs the "real" account was the issue. I thought I had signed in under the real account but evidently not...my bad. Things to be running much smoother and settings are being saved. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If you were actually using the guest user and now you have solved, mark the answer as correct. Regards.